# Are values of a list/dictionary emptied outside the loop (more details...)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

So what I am trying to accomplish is to check if a value exists in a list and if it does the loop should skip it...it seems though that this doesn't work.

Here is the desired algorithm:

1. Read text file line by line, every line is an url.
2. For every url go to the url and grab json string from this url
3. check if this json string  is unique or already exists in our list.
4. if it exists...do nothing, if it doesn't: add it to our list and do other things

point 4 is the problem? I am catching only partial duplicate values, that is if the same duplicate value but not all duplicates values?

What I want is to catch duplicates even if they exist from different urls? I have declared the list on the very top outside of the loop but still can't catch it?

Example:

```
 inputs = [] #define the list outside the loop to make sure it gets populated with every single json string

 for url_to_get_data_from in file: #for every url...
  while y < 50: 

    item =  str(json_string_from_the_internet[y]) 
    #this item is sometimes unique but not always...

   if(item in inputs): #lets see if this json string is in the list

     print("This already exists in our inputs list, so we skip it")

   else:
    inputs.append(item) #add the item for the upcoming loop cycles
      print("this item does not exist in our inputs, we continue with our code below")

  print("no more while loop and no more urls...done with work)
```

Comment: You should use `continue` to skip it as explained [there](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: @Nenri: will try this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(item in inputs): #lets see if this json string is in the list

   pass

else:
  inputs.append(item) #add the item for the upcoming loop cycles
  print("this item does not exist in our inputs, we continue with our code below")
```

or you can try this  :

```
  if(item  not in inputs):
        inputs.append(item)
```

Comment: thanx, well i found another very different solution without pass/continue but it seemed as the issue would persist even if i fix this anyway.

Comment: no problem , If you can please show more details I will try to fixe it

Answer (score 0):

In python blocks of code are denoted by line indentation, which is rigidly enforced, all statements within the block must be indented the same amount.
Your code as entered above does not follow the indentation requirement. For example, if I understand your code correctly the "item =" statement should have the same indentation as "if" and "else" but does not. The statements included in "else:" also have different indentation.
I would suggest to fix the indentation first and then check if the problem still exists.

Comment: I know! :) And frankly I kind of hate that, as a c++/c# kind of person I love brackets..the whole whitespace thing in Python still amazes me, I am even mixing tabs and spaces in the same program, so this may be an issue like you said..